Identification of plant gall / seed pod
I hope someone can anyone identify this plant material found in a meadow beside a river in UK. The nearest trees are about 50m away, across the river.
It is about 10cm long; flattish, soft and fleshy. There is a suggestion of a stalk at one end. It's been trodden on, so it might be squashed.
The first two pictures show it from each side, the third is a detail of the second side.
My searches have variously suggested

A caterpillar.

A gall from a hornbeam tree.

A seed pod of a mangolia tree.






It makes me think of a rhizome of a small water lilly, but I only have the picture to go by.

@Willeke that's an interesting suggestion. Perhaps it looked like the linked picture once, before being beaten up and had insect eggs laid in it.

Weather Vane, if comparing the item you have with descriptions of rhizomes bring you to a positive identification, can you please post it as a self answer?

Magnolia sprang to mind for me too; definitely not caterpillar. I don't think the "stalk" is really a stalk

@bob1 certainly not a caterpillar. If it's a rhizome the 'stalk' is more likely to be a root. The two sides look different, and in the alamy link the roots are coming from one side. Perhaps the pock-marks are root nodes and not insect exit holes.

...and the roots seem to grow out in groups. The pockmarks in my picture 2 are in groups.

@WeatherVane it bears some resemblance to Oxalis tuberosa, so a root/rhizome/tuber could well be right.

...except that seems to occur in the high Andes.

@WeatherVane consumed in many parts of the world (particuarly southern hemisphere/Pacific) as "yams", though of course it isn't a true yam.
